# getSymbols when tickers list is a dataframe

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm trying to use `getSymbols` with my own set of tickers.

I have the tickers imported from a csv file with 55 tickers. But, how can I read the Tickers dataframe correctly when running the getSymbols?

Currently I'm having a NULL error when I run the code below.

```
library(quantmod)
Tickers <- read.csv("nasdaq_tickers_list.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
getSymbols(Tickers,from="2018-01-01", src="yahoo" )
```

If I run `class(Tickers)` it is a data.frame.

What I'm doing wrong?  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the helpfile for `getSymbols` by doing `?getSymbols`, you'll see that the first argument needs to be "a *character vector* specifying the names of each symbol to be loaded".  To get a character vector rather than a dataframe, do this:

```
getSymbols(Tickers$VARNAME, ...)
```

where `VARNAME` is the column name of the ticker column in your dataframe.

Comment: Thanks Dan. The problem was my .csv has not a colname on it, once I put the name after $, worked fine.

Comment: Great - glad it was an easy fix